# How to create a D3 force directed graph having nodes as divs

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am creating a force directed graph using D3. But the issue which I am having is I have Divs containing other divs as nodes. And there are clicks events binded on inner divs.
All the examples I came across had circles as nodes, I have created some graph using rectengles but I cannot implement all the functionality. Is there a way I can put divs directly inside D3 graphs as nodes.
Thanks.

Also the div structure is like:

```
<div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

with events binded to 'a' and 'b' divs.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298289/d3-js-force-on-non-svg-elements) may help.

Comment: This is not a problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298289/d3-js-force-on-non-svg-elements