# D3 Force Graph in SolidJS with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, d3.js, graph, solid-js

D3 seems so complicated to make work with basically *any* framework... Specially when it comes to TypeScript, since they apparently keep changing their APIs, rendering so many past examples from gists and other posts close to useless.

At the moment, I would like to make work with TypeScript and SolidJS [the canonical force graph example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph).

I feel like trying to solve a jigsaw puzzle since a lot of the types just won't match. The one I've had the most trouble with was the `drag()` arguments, I believe. I've also tried simply ignoring types, of course, but I couldn't make it work either.

Also, does anyone know if it is possible to append any arbitrary component as a graph node?

---

### References

1. [D3 - *Force Directed Graph*](https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph)
2. [CM-Tech's *D3 Graph for a SolidJS Debugger (in TypeScript)*](https://github.com/CM-Tech/solid-debugger/blob/main/src/graph.tsx)
3. [*Easily show relationships — Draw Simple Force Graph with React & d3 utilizing TypeScript*](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/easily-show-relationships-draw-simple-force-graph-with-react-d3-utilizing-typescript-d7e9d5326b6)
4. [*Building D3 interactive network graph D3 Force-Simulation + React + TypeScript*](https://balramchavan.medium.com/building-d3-interactive-network-graph-d3-force-simulation-react-typescript-b17e71f03913)
5. [mbostock's Gist](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/2675ff61ea5e063ede2b5d63c08020c7)
6. [steveharoz's Gist with Full Controls](https://gist.github.com/steveharoz/8c3e2524079a8c440df60c1ab72b5d03)
7. [YouTube - React Tutorials & Tips For ReactJs, d3 Developers - *Integrating d3.js with React - Force Chart - Force network graph - Intro and setting up*](https://youtu.be/gKgWGpvn0W4)
8. [YouTube - React Tutorials & Tips For ReactJs, d3 Developers - *Integrating d3.js with React - Force Chart - Force network graph - Network graph graphics*](https://youtu.be/AvlkcRS9-pw)

Comment: Could you show the TS code that you have, so that readers can look at the problems you had with `drag()` arguments?

Comment: I'll try to get it back from git history, cause I've deleted about 3 attempts already, and in none the code was presentable. To be fair, it didn't look very different from the gists in the references or the YouTube tutorials.

Comment: I suspect that, without code in the question, this may be closed under the official close reasons of Needs Focus or Recommendation/Resources or Needs Debugging Details (needs a [mcve]), so it is worth showing that code if you can. The links to Gists are welcome, but without code, the question is not "self contained", which is generally required here.

Comment: The minimal reproducible example is [**exactly** what's on the D3 docs](https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph), but on SolidJS with TypeScript (I could paste it here if that's enough). The gists themselves have code, I see very little need for me to paste it here.

Comment: No, officially, the bounty prompt lists *attracting attention* as only **one** of the reasons. In this case, I'm trying to solve something I've had trouble implementing for the past 2-3 days. You're free to judge otherwise, and also free to not answer the question if you want.

Comment: Regarding the problem of free work: I would reward monetarily a successful answer to this question, if SO had this feature (e.g. donation), I do have the money. The reason I opted for asking a question here is because I do think people will benefit from it in the future. Other SolidJS and D3 users will learn how to do it, how rendering animations work in Solid with TS, etc. I think it's a good future reference. At any rate, if nobody is willing to answer, I'll eventually solve the problem and answer it myself.

Comment: I am [transferring this discussion to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254980/discussion-between-halfer-and-philippe-fanaro).

Comment: (I've removed some of my meta comments here for reasons of tidying).

Comment: Seems so silly to close the question after an answer has already been given. I didn't add any details to it because @0xts beat me to it by giving the exact answer I was looking for, the code is already there, most people just skip to the answer anyways.

Comment: Hi Philippe - my interpretation of the on-topic guidelines is that questions can/should be put on hold if they are not on-topic. This is because if a link breaks, the question may not make sense for new readers, and any supplied answers will have lost some important context. But if you can supply the relevant part of the code, in the question itself, I will help you re-open it.

Comment: I appreciate that this feels like a faff, but it is (in my opinion) how Stack Overflow retains its high quality levels - the material here is curated.

Comment: In my opinion, closing this question doesn't improve the quality of anything. It only makes it harder for other people looking for the same answer to either trust or find this content. Following the rules to a T doesn't necessarily mean quality, SO rules are heuristics, not a math formula for quality.

Comment: Putting questions on hold or deleting answers, where they rely on links and not content, is pretty normal here. You can post to _Meta Stack Overflow_ if you would like to discuss it, but I would expect that it would be rather less hassle just to edit the question with the suggested improvement .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a FDG (Force Directed Graph) like the one in the [docs example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph) using SolidJS, there's very little that's SolidJS specific, it's mostly about knowing how d3 works and what function invocation does what and through that one knows where to do what (whether to use a side effect, or do something on mounting etc., which is what I'm referring to as "where").

#### Issues with Typescript

Most of the methods make use of typescript generics and infer the types from the arguments, however, at times it's better to just add the type parameters. To not to have issues with types, here's a little tip -

***Always check the return, parameter types of the function calls, go to library source if you need to and then add the typings accordingly***

You had issues with the `d3.drag` because by default, the generics take an `unknown` type (unless they're assigned a default type), if you're explicit in the call with the type parameters, ts doesn't complain.

#### FDG Docs Example with SolidJS

[Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/minimal-d3-force-solidjs-ht7s5s?file=/src/FDG.tsx) how you can create a graph like the one in example -

```ts
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { onMount } from "solid-js";

interface FDGNode extends d3.SimulationNodeDatum {
  id: string;
  group: number;
}

interface FDGLink extends d3.SimulationLinkDatum<FDGNode> {
  value: number;
}

export type FDGData = {
  nodes: Array<FDGNode>;
  links: Array<FDGLink>;
};

let svgRef: SVGSVGElement | undefined;

export default function ForceDirectedGraph(props: {
  children?: never;
  data: FDGData;
}) {
  const width = 928;
  const height = 600;
  const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

  const links = props.data.links.map((d) => ({ ...d }));
  const nodes = props.data.nodes.map((d) => ({ ...d }));

  onMount(() => {
    if (svgRef) {
      const simulation = d3
        .forceSimulation(nodes)
        .force(
          "link",
          d3.forceLink<FDGNode, FDGLink>(links).id((d) => d.id)
        )
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

      const link = d3
        .select<SVGSVGElement, FDGNode>(svgRef)
        .selectAll<SVGLineElement, FDGLink>("line")
        .data(links);

      const node = d3
        .select<SVGSVGElement, FDGNode>(svgRef)
        .selectAll<SVGCircleElement, FDGNode>("circle")
        .data(nodes);

      function ticked() {
        link
// The source property comes from the SimulationLinkDatum interface, and by default,
// has a type of TypeOfNode | string | number, where TypeOfNode is FDGNode in this example
// so we need to make an as assertion. The x,y properties added by the SimulationNodeDatum
// interface are of type number | undefined, so a non-null assertion operator is used
          .attr("x1", (d) => (d.source as FDGNode).x!)  
          .attr("y1", (d) => (d.source as FDGNode).y!)
          .attr("x2", (d) => (d.target as FDGNode).x!)
          .attr("y2", (d) => (d.target as FDGNode).y!);

        node.attr("cx", (d) => d.x!).attr("cy", (d) => d.y!);
      }
      simulation.on("tick", ticked);

      function dragstarted(
        event: d3.D3DragEvent<SVGCircleElement, FDGNode, FDGNode>
      ) {
        if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
        event.subject.fx = event.subject.x;
        event.subject.fy = event.subject.y;
      }

      function dragged(
        event: d3.D3DragEvent<SVGCircleElement, FDGNode, FDGNode>
      ) {
        event.subject.fx = event.x;
        event.subject.fy = event.y;
      }

      function dragended(
        event: d3.D3DragEvent<SVGCircleElement, FDGNode, FDGNode>
      ) {
        if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
        event.subject.fx = null;
        event.subject.fy = null;
      }

      node.call(
        d3
          .drag<SVGCircleElement, FDGNode>()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended)
      );
    }
  });

  return (
    <svg
      ref={svgRef}
      width={width}
      height={height}
      viewBox={`0 0 ${width} ${height}`}
      style={{
        "max-width": "100%",
        height: "auto"
      }}
    >
      <g stroke="#999" stroke-opacity={0.6}>
        {links.map((link) => {
          return <line stroke-width={Math.sqrt(link.value)} />;
        })}
      </g>
      <g stroke={"#fff"} stroke-width={1.5}>
        {nodes.map((node) => (
          <circle r={5} fill={color(`${node.group}`)}>
            <title>{node.id}</title>
          </circle>
        ))}
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
}
```

#### Graph Nodes

Once a simulation is rendered (in the particular example from the docs, using an svg container) the interaction inside of the FDG is handled by d3 only, so not much is required in terms of re-rendering from SolidJS. Since it's an svg container, it can only have [svg elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element) as children.

However, it's entirely possible to be able to use any arbitrary component as a graph node, for that, one will have to ***not use*** an `svg` container (unless you're willing to use `path` elements to draw paths, then use an `svg` container), so maybe a `div` container? With that, the configuration for all the interactions has to be done by adding all the different handlers, a tad bit like the [CM-Tech's D3 Graph for a SolidJS Debugger (in TypeScript)](https://github.com/CM-Tech/solid-debugger/blob/main/src/graph.tsx) example that you've linked in your question. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298289/d3-js-force-layout-on-non-svg-elements) question for more details.

Comment: When it comes to the use of an arbitrary component instead of an `svg`: is it really possible? I think D3 uses the `svg` to move things around like in a `canvas`? (I could ask a new question, if you feel like you have a quick answer.) I wasn't able to do it, I ended up opting for adding an overlay `div` in which I draw and position a widget whenever the user hovers over a node.

Comment: If you also happen to be good at SQL, I think I'm gonna add a bounty to [this question (*Recursive Breadth Traversal Query (with max depth), Returning Nested JSON, Filtering the Initial Seed*)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76940588/4756173).

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro Sure, we can exchange contacts, I'll ping you on Twitter or Instagram. For your requirement with using `div` container for d3, could you post a question with detailed requirements of what you're trying to achieve and what have you tried so far? I'll try to answer it. I'll also take a look at the SQL question to try and answer it.